# Detect when angular page is loaded by link

Tags: angular

Each of my routes should be able to perform some actions based on whether this route was navigated to using angular `Router`, or route was opened by pasting the link into browser url bar (or clicked on link in an email).

The problem i am facing is that i have no way (yet) of knowing how my route was opened. I tried to use `document.referrer` thinking, that if you paste the link, referrer will be empty, but if you navigate using router, it should be filled. I was wrong. It was empty both times.

Is there any options which would help me achieve goal?

Comment: why do you want to if it was opened directly or via link from page?

Comment: So i can perform actions when page is loaded via link and perform different actions when page was navigated to.